Proving a the distance between Cauchy sequences converges
Assume we have two Cauchy sequences { $x_n$ } and {$y_n$} in the metric space $(X,d)$. Is it true that the sequence {$a_n$}$=d(x_n,y_n)$ is convergent in $\mathbb{R}$? Here is my try: $$$$
Since those sequences are Cauchy it means that for:
$$\forall \varepsilon>0,\exists N \ \ \ \text{such that}\ \ \ d(x_n,x_m)<\varepsilon \ \ \& \ \ d(y_n,y_m)<\varepsilon \ , \ \ \forall n,m>N$$
Then surely:
$$\exists N \ \ \ \text{such that}\ \ \ |d(x_n,x_m)-d(y_n,y_m)|<\varepsilon$$
Now by the tiangle inequality we have:
$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
d(x_n,y_n) \leq d(x_n,x_m) +d(x_m,y_n)\\
d(x_m,y_m) \leq d(y_m,y_n) +d(y_n,x_m)
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
$$
Now if we subtract the second from the first (and the first from the second) and then write the triangle inequality in a different way and do the same we can get to $|d(x_m,y_m)-d(x_n,y_n)|\leq|d(x_n,x_m)-d(y_n,y_m)|$ which combined with the upper inequality gives us $|a_m-a_n|<\varepsilon$ and by the completeness of $\mathbb{R}$ it means that $a_n$ converges. My question is about that step with the inequalities. How can we just subtract one from the other? Why wouldnt that result in nonsense? Here is an example:
$$\begin{cases}
5<10\\
5<11
\end{cases}\\(1)-(2): 0<-1$$
Can you explain why when dealing with the triangle inequality we can just subtract them like that and it still gives the right answer?

$|d(x_m,y_m)-d(x_n,y_n)|\le|d(x_n,x_m)-d(y_n,y_m)|$ is false. What is true (and sufficient) is $|d(x_m,y_m)-d(x_n,y_n)|\le d(x_n,x_m)+d(y_n,y_m)$. Anyway, your post is a megadupe.
